# How to do a SOAP wsdl web services call from the command line

Tags: soap, wsdl

I need to make a SOAP webservice call to https://sandbox.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl and to use the operation ClientLogin while passing through the parameters: ApplicationKey, Password, and UserName. The response is UserSecurityToken. They are all strings.

Here is the link fully explaining what I am trying to do:
https://sandbox.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API.Doc/?v=3

How can I do this on the command line? (Windows and/or Linux would be helpful)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It's a standard, ordinary SOAP web service. SSH has nothing to do here. I just called it with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) (one-liner):

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
    -H 'SOAPAction: "http://api.eyeblaster.com/IAuthenticationService/ClientLogin"' \
    --data-binary @request.xml \
    https://sandbox.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/AuthenticationService.svc
```

Where `request.xml` file has the following contents:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://api.eyeblaster.com/">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <api:ClientLogin>
                 <api:username>user</api:username>
                 <api:password>password</api:password>
                 <api:applicationKey>key</api:applicationKey>
              </api:ClientLogin>
          </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get this beautiful 500:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Security.Authentication.UserPassIncorrect</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The username, password or application key is incorrect.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Have you tried [soapui](/questions/tagged/soapui)?

[Read more](http://dasunhegoda.com/make-soap-request-command-line-curl/596/)

Comment: +1 soapui, a very useful and free tool for working with soap-based web services.  Much better than using the command line IMHO.

Comment: Which version of curl are you using? Mine says "Couldn't resolve host '--data-binary', and that https is an "Unsupported protocol".

Comment: If I do exactly what you did, then I always get an error from mediamind that says that "An unexpected internal server error has occurred." Is there any thing that you did not include in the answer that I should be doing (besides for replacing the un/pw/key with the real ones)?

Comment: @Marina: now I get "*500 Internal Server Error*" as well. However this is a server-side error, not ours (?), ask the WS provider what's happening. It was working few days ago.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a missing /Envelope in request.xml, causing an error response from the server. Once I added that it worked fine. Maybe that's the issue for other folks getting errors.

Comment: Next to soapui, postman is also a very powerful tool. Not just for REST-api’s, but for soap-messages too!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I just had to use: `"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"` instead of `"Content-Type: text/xml"`.

Answer (score 28):

On linux command line, you can simply execute:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:"  -d @your_soap_request.xml -X POST https://ws.paymentech.net/PaymentechGateway
```

Answer (score 25):

Here is another sample CURL - SOAP ([WSDL](http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl)) request for bank [swift codes](https://bank-code.net/blz-sort-codes)

**Request**

```
curl -X POST http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  -H 'SOAPAction: blz:getBank' \
  -d '
  <soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <blz:getBank>
        <blz:blz>10020200</blz:blz>
      </blz:getBank>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>'
```

**Response**

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 08:14:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 395
< 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getBankResponse
      xmlns:ns1="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">
      <ns1:details>
        <ns1:bezeichnung>BHF-BANK</ns1:bezeichnung>
        <ns1:bic>BHFBDEFF100</ns1:bic>
        <ns1:ort>Berlin</ns1:ort>
        <ns1:plz>10117</ns1:plz>
      </ns1:details>
    </ns1:getBankResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: +1 for indicating several header lines (another -H), and as it is neat to have all in one location. Worked in SAP context.

Answer (score 16):

Using CURL:

```
SOAP_USER='myusername'
PASSWORD='mypassword'
AUTHENTICATION="$SOAP_USER:$PASSWORD"
URL='http://mysoapserver:8080/meeting/aws'
SOAPFILE=getCurrentMeetingStatus.txt
TIMEOUT=5
```

CURL request:

```
curl --user "${AUTHENTICATION}" --header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' --data @"${SOAPFILE}" "${URL}" --connect-timeout $TIMEOUT
```

I use this to verify response:

```
http_code=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" --silent --user "${AUTHENTICATION}" --header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' --data @"${SOAPFILE}" "${URL}" --connect-timeout $TIMEOUT --output /dev/null)
if [[ $http_code -gt 400 ]];  # 400 and 500 Client and Server Error codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
then
echo "Error: HTTP response ($http_code) getting URL: $URL"
echo "Please verify parameters/backend. Username: $SOAP_USER Password: $PASSWORD Press any key to continue..."
read entervalue || continue
fi
```

Comment: $USERNAME resolves to my linux username, changed to $USER in my scripts

Answer (score 5):

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL" --data @FILE_NAME URL_OF_THE_SERVICE
```

Above command was helpful for me

Example

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:GetVehicleLimitedInfo" --data @request.xml http://11.22.33.231:9080/VehicleInfoQueryService.asmx
```

[More info](http://dasunhegoda.com/make-soap-request-command-line-curl/596/)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users looking for a PowerShell alternative, here it is (using POST).  I've split it up onto multiple lines for readability.

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/AuthenticationService.svc'
$headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'text/xml';
    'SOAPAction' = 'http://api.eyeblaster.com/IAuthenticationService/ClientLogin'
}
$envelope = @'
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <yourEnvelopeContentsHere/>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
'@     # <--- This line must not be indented

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method POST -Body $envelope
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows:

Save the following as MSFT.vbs:

```
set SOAPClient = createobject("MSSOAP.SOAPClient")
SOAPClient.mssoapinit "https://sandbox.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl"
WScript.Echo "MSFT = " & SOAPClient.GetQuote("MSFT")
```

Then from a command prompt, run:

```
C:\>MSFT.vbs
```

Reference:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgroth/archive/2004/10/21/246155.aspx

Comment: This year 2004 technique fails on Window 7 at least.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows I found this working:

```
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
http.open "GET", "http://www.mywebservice.com/webmethod.asmx?WSDL", FALSE
http.send ""
WScript.Echo http.responseText
```

Reference: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/266002/Invoke-a-Webservice-from-a-Batch-file)