# Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from Progress 4GL

Tags: web-services, character-encoding, response, iso-8859-1, progress-4gl

I'm use progress 4Gl and i have to call a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 but i receive the error when a execute the run statment:

***Error receiving Web Service Response: Cannot get 'ISO-8859-1' transcoder from the TranscoderRepository. (11773)***

And the developer of webservice can not change the encoding.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Progress only supports the UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding with the OpenEdge Web Services as required by the WS-I

According to [this knowledgebase entry](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P97707?q=TranscoderRepository&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1)

Comment: So there is no solution?

Comment: Perhaps you could try something like in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222607/how-to-do-a-soap-wsdl-web-services-call-from-the-command-line - save the response to disc and then parse it. Not very nice though.

Comment: I tried to do what you say, but the problem is that I fail to get the response because the RUN statement throws the error above described

Comment: Using curl or other tool would eliminate the RUN-statement altogether. You would need to: Create a request, call curl, save resulting xml to file, parse xml any way you prefer (X-DOCUMENT, DATASET etc) and then handle the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the data is standard ascii (character values with ascii value < 128) there is a work-around.

- You download the wsdl of the webservice locally.
- Replace iso8859-1 but utf-8 in the locally saved file.
- Use that wsdl instead of the one from the webservice.

***This is a work-around, not an ideal solution.***

Comment: I already did, but when running a webservice operation throws the same error. Apparently there are more xml with  iso8859-1 which I have no access.