# CPU usage of IBM DataPower with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performance testing IBM data Power XI52 box.
I am running Jmeter from Linux Box.

Can any one let me know how to get CPU usage and Memory usage details of
DataPower using Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

First, you must [enable the XMI (XML Management Interface)](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4446.html)

Then you can use XMI Requests to get CPU Usage through SOAP. You send this message:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <dp:request xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
            <dp:get-status class="CPUUsage"/>
        </dp:request>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And you'll get this, detailing the CPU Usage in the last ten seconds, one minute, ten minutes, one hour and one day:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
            <dp:timestamp>2009-09-24T11:56:22-04:00</dp:timestamp>
            <dp:status>
                <CPUUsage xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                    <tenSeconds>1</tenSeconds>
                    <oneMinute>1</oneMinute>
                    <tenMinutes>1</tenMinutes>
                    <oneHour>1</oneHour>
                    <oneDay>1</oneDay>
                </CPUUsage>
            </dp:status>
        </dp:response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Now, using CURL (as seen in the same IBM Document and [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222607/how-to-do-a-soap-wsdl-web-services-call-from-the-command-line)) and xmllint as seen in [this unix stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83385/parse-xml-to-get-node-value-in-bash-script) you can get the CPU usage in a bash script.

Now, execute this script using the [Exec reader](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/) jMeter plugin to read the CPU Metrics in your test.

If you want memory, instead of `CPUUsage` you can request `MemoryStatus`. Check the full list in page 31 of the document.