# Soap requests with Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl, soap

How can I make Soap request using Curl php by using below soap format and url? I have tried avaliable solutions online and none of them worked out.

```
$soap_request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:alisonwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <soap:Header>
            <credentials>
                <alisonOrgId>9ReXlYlpOThe24AWisE</alisonOrgId>
                <alisonOrgKey>C2owrOtRegikaroXaji</alisonOrgKey>
            </credentials>
          </soap:Header>
          <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <q1:login xmlns:q1="urn:alisonwsdl">
                <email xsi:type="xsd:string">email</email>
                <firstname xsi:type="xsd:string">fname</firstname>
                <lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">lname</lastname>
                <city xsi:type="xsd:string">city</city>
                <country xsi:type="xsd:string">country</country>
                <external_id xsi:type="xsd:string"></external_id>
            </q1:login>
          </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

 Url
https://alison.com/api/service.php?wsdl
```

Comment: What exactly did you try & why didn't they work? Here's another answer for a similar scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222750/2173960. If you're still not getting desired output, then do post what you tried. Also, just in case you're only looking for a simple & free tool, try SoapUI.

Comment: Note also that PHP has a built-in [SOAP Client](http://php.net/soapclient) which aims to help you connect to standard SOAP services.

Comment: Oh, and I really hope that isn't your real authentication key that you've just posted to a public website!

Comment: That's real authentication key @IMSoP

Comment: For some reason I have tried to use SoapClient and clas not found error is returned though I have enabled soap extension

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine Cool! Can I have your Stack Overflow password and your bank details as well please? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a week I was able to find something in this tutorial here on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V_myufS89A and I was able to send requests to the API successifuly, first read my xml format above before continuing with my solution

```
     $options = array('trace'=> true, "exception" => 0);

    $client  = new \SoapClient('your url to wsdl',$options);

   //if you have Authorization parameters in your xml like mine above use SoapVar and SoapHeader as me below

    $params = new \stdClass();
    $params->alisonOrgId = 'value here';
    $params->alisonOrgKey = 'value here';

    $authentication_parameters = new \SoapVar($params,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

    $header = new \SoapHeader('your url to wsdl','credentials',$authentication_parameters);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));


   print_r($client->__soapCall("Function here",'Function parameter here or left it as null if has no parameter'));

    //or call your function by

     print_r($client->yourFunction($function_parameters));

    }
```

Hope this will help someone out there struggling with soap requests that contains authentication informations

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have php_soap extension installed, you can access the SOAP API like this:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('https://alison.com/api/service.php?wsdl', array(
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false, 
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    ))
));
```

You might want to define the header for authentication as well

```
$auth = array(
    'alisonOrgId' => '9ReXlYlpOThe24AWisE',
    'alisonOrgKey' => 'C2owrOtRegikaroXaji'
);

$header = new SoapHeader('https://alison.com/api/service.php?wsdl', 'credentials', $auth, false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Then you can get the list of functions available

```
// Get function list
$functions = $client->__getFunctions ();
echo "<pre>";
var_dump ($functions);
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

Or call a function right away, like this:

```
// Run the function
$obj = $client->__soapCall("emailExists", array(
    "email" => "test@email.com"
));
echo "<pre>";
var_dump ($obj);
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

Comment: Note that in most cases, you don't need to call `__soapCall`; in your example, you could write `$client->emailExists(array( "email" => "test@email.com"));`

Comment: I have credentials for that API on the header how do I attach them using SoapClient()?

Comment: Thank alot Adlan but now am having this error "auth error", I don't know why this come from and I have configured everything correctly

Comment: It is highlighting error is here when I try to use this metthod $client->getUserId('t****@gmail.com');

Comment: Change your parameter inside your header. The ```alisonOrgId``` and ```C2owrOtRegikaroXaji``` is just a sample

Comment: I have already updated them to real one but nothin seems to work and when I remove header part some functions return data @Adlan Arif Zakaria

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine Please do not expect users of an online forum to give you free private consultation. If you have further questions which would be a fit for this site as defined in the [help] then feel free to ask a new question. If you need more detailed help than that, I suggest you pay someone for their time.

Comment: @IMSoP I have realized that the problem comes from Soap header it is not authenticating correctly, How do I recognize namespace because I dont know how to set it

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine This is not the right place to ask follow-up questions. Take the [tour] so you can understand how this site works and how to get the most out of it.